# Duplicate DB records in spring batch Partitioning

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-batch, batch-processing, partitioning

I have a spring batch script configured to read millions of records from one DB table and apply some logic and store into another DB table, and I am trying to process it with local thread based partioning, but seeing each partions are processing all the records.

And the databased used here is Postgres.

Ex: assuming 10 records with grid size 5, expecting each partion to process two records, but all partions are processing all the 10 records.

here is the code snippet of my batch job, am I missing anything which is causing this issue?.

```
**Reader**
public JdbcPagingItemReader<User> itemReader(final DataSource dataSource,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['id']}") String id) {

    JdbcPagingItemReader<User> jdbcPagingItemReader = new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<User>()
            .name("db_reader").dataSource(dataSource).queryProvider(createQuery(dataSource))
            .rowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(User.class)).pageSize(10).saveState(false)
            .build();
    jdbcPagingItemReader.setMaxItemCount(10);
    return jdbcPagingItemReader;
}

**Query Provider**
private PagingQueryProvider createQuery(DataSource dataSource) {
    SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean bean = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
    bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    bean.setSelectClause("*");
    bean.setFromClause("users");
    bean.setSortKey("ID");
    return  bean.getObject();
}



public Step slaveStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
        ItemProcessor itemProcessor, Writer writer, final DataSource dataSource) {
    return  new StepBuilder("Step-worker", jobRepository).chunk(300, transactionManager)
            .reader(itemProcessor(dataSource, "#{jobParameters['id']}"))
            .processor(itemProcessor).writer(writer).build();       
}

@Bean
public Step masterStep(JobRepository jobRepository,Step taxGenerationStep,DataSource dataSource) {
    return new StepBuilder("Step-master", jobRepository).
            partitioner(slaveStep.getName(), partitioner(dataSource))
            .partitionHandler(partitionHandler(slaveStep))
            .build();
}

@Bean   
public TaskExecutorPartitionHandler partitionHandler(Step slaveStep) {
    TaskExecutorPartitionHandler taskExecutorPartitionHandler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
    taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setGridSize(10);       
    taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
    taskExecutorPartitionHandler.setStep(slaveStep);
    return taskExecutorPartitionHandler;
}


**Partioner**
@Bean
public ColumnRangePartitioner partitioner(DataSource dataSource) 
{
    ColumnRangePartitioner columnRangePartitioner = new ColumnRangePartitioner();
    columnRangePartitioner.setColumn("id");
    columnRangePartitioner.setDataSource(dataSource);
    columnRangePartitioner.setTable("users");
    return columnRangePartitioner;
}



public class ColumnRangePartitioner implements Partitioner 
{
    @Autowired
  private JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate;
  private String table;
  private String column;
 
  public void setTable(String table) {
    this.table = table;
  }
 
  public void setColumn(String column) {
    this.column = column;
  }
 
  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }

 
  @Override
  public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) 
  {
    int min = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MIN(" + column + ") FROM " + table, Integer.class);
    int max = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MAX(" + column + ") FROM " + table, Integer.class);
    
    int targetSize = (max - min) / gridSize + 1;
 
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<>();
 
    int number = 0;
    int start = min;
    int end = start + targetSize - 1;
     
    while (start <= max) 
    {
      ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();
      result.put("partition" + number, value);
       
      if(end >= max) {
        end = max;
      }
       
      value.putInt("minValue", start);
      value.putInt("maxValue", end);
 
      start += targetSize;
      end += targetSize;
 
      number++;
    }  
    return result;
  }
}
```

I felt initially it is due to the sorting/ordering is missing in the select query, added the sortKey but still the same issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Your item reader is not configured to read data from the partition (note how `jobParameters['id']` is not used). It should be configured to read items in the range (`[minValue,maxValue]`) specified by the partitioner in the step execution context. Here is an example based on what you shared:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcPagingItemReader<User> itemReader(final DataSource dataSource,
        @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['minValue']}") Integer minValue,
        @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['maxValue']}") Integer maxValue) {

    // TODO use minValue and maxValue to configure the reader to read items
    // from that range

}
```